# Let-Defined Limits for \foreach Loop with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to compute the upper and lower limits of a TikZ `\foreach` loop using the `let` statement. Unfortunately, this throws errors when I try code along the following lines:

```
\draw
let \n{lo}={<computation>},
    \n{hi}={<computation>}
in
\foreach \var in {\n{lo},...,\n{hi}} { <STUFF> }
```

I can easily define a tail-recursive macro that does what I want but ideally I'd like to use TikZ's `\foreach` statement. Interestingly, the `\n{lo}` isn't causing problems (in my case) but the `\n{hi}` is...

Any pointers to a solution appreciated.

Here's a minimal-ish example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw
  let \p{bl}=(0,0),
      \p{br}=(1,0),
      % THIS COMPUTATION IS RELATED TO THE PROBLEM
      % \n{line width}={1} % WORKS FINE
      \n{line width}={\x{br}-\x{bl}},
      \n{x height}={1.2},
      \n{line density}={2},
      \n{x heights}={\n{line width}/\n{x height}},
      \n{aid lines}={ceil(\n{line density} * \n{x heights})},
      \n{aid line factor}={\n{x height} / \n{line density}},
      \n{first}={-10},
      \n{last}={\n{aid lines}-\n{first}}
  in
  % DOESN'T WORK
  \foreach \cpcnt in {\n{first},...,\n{last}} {%
       (\p{bl}) -- + (\cpcnt * \n{aid line factor},0)
  };%
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: works for me. Depends on what you have in `<STUFF>`

Comment: A minimal non working example is needed, in my simple test I have no problem.

Comment: @percusse Yes. Sometimes it doesn't work and sometimes it does. Clearly (IMHO) it's a bug in TikZ. I have a complex example but it wouldn't help if I posted it. I'll see if I can isolate the problem but I'm afraid it won't help...

Comment: If it works sometimes, then it is not a bug.

Comment: @percusse You got to be joking!

Comment: @egreg Minimal-ish non-working example posted.

Comment: @werner No I don't think so. `\x{point register}` gives the x-coordinate of the point defined as `\p{point register}`.

Comment: The result of `\n{.}` macros are with dimensions (because you would use them in drawings), in your case it is 58pt. So when it is used in foreach it becomes `{-10.0,...,58pt}` and trips up. So it is not a bug.

Comment: @percusse Thanks. Much appreciated. Will have a look at that. Still odd, the `\n{}` sometimes works and sometimes doesn't. Thanks again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can see the difference between the working and the non-working versions from

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw
  let \p{bl}=(0,0),
      \p{br}=(1,0),
      \n{a}={1},
      \n{b}={\x{br}-\x{bl}}
  in
   node {$a=\n{a}$, $b=\n{b}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which outputs

[image: output of above code]

`\n` macros can be dimensionless number or a dimension, cf. the manual page 160 (for version 3.0.1a, in section 14.15 *The Let Operation*). `\n{b}` becomes a dimension because `\x` has a dimension.

You can strip the dimension with the `scalar` function, but you might need scale it afterward:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw
  let \p{bl}=(0,0),
      \p{br}=(1,0),
      \n{a}={1},
      \n{b}={scalar(\x{br}-\x{bl})},
      \n{c}={scalar(\x{br}-\x{bl})*2.54/72.27} % scale from points to cm
  in
   node {$a=\n{a}$, $b=\n{b}$, $c=\n{c}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: output of above snippet]

Hence, in your example you might want to use

```
\n{line width}={scalar(\x{br}-\x{bl})*2.54/72.27},
```

Comment: Thanks. The last time I read the TikZ manual was a few years ago. I cannot recall anything about values with and without units. The `scalar` function is what I'm looking for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen I had the wrong page reference by the way, should have been 160 not 560.

Comment: No problem. I found it. I'll also try to send you something I should have sent earlier this year!

Comment: @MarcvanDongen Oh, don't worry about that, it's not a big deal.